# Problem retrieving data from json output

Tags: json, facebook, fbjs

I am a noob when it comes to json. The more I use it, I am starting to like it. I have a output that looks like this

```
[
    {
        "product": {
            "id": "6",
            "category": "Books",
            "created": "2010-04-13 15:15:18",
        },
        "availability": [
            {
                "country": "United Kingdom",
                "price": "$13.99",
            },
            {
                "country": "Germany",
                "price": "$13.99",
            }
        ]            
    }
]
```

Actually I have listed only one product, But output has many products listed. I want to loop through this json output and get all the product's category, countries where they are available and price using fbjs.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to loop through the parsed JSON?

Comment: @theycallmemorty i thought i will use $.each method but i dont know the same in fbjs.

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON is like this,

```
var products = [
    {
        "product": {
            "id": "6",
            "category": "Books",
            "created": "2010-04-13 15:15:18",
        },
        "availability": [
            {
                "country": "United Kingdom",
                "price": "$13.99",
            },
            {
                "country": "Germany",
                "price": "$13.99",
            }
        ]            
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "id": "7",
            "category": "Books",
            "created": "2010-04-13 15:15:18",
        },
        "availability": [
            {
                "country": "United Kingdom",
                "price": "$13.99",
            },
            {
                "country": "Germany",
                "price": "$13.99",
            }
        ]            
    }
]
```

You can iterate through:

```
for(var index = 0; index < products.length; index++) {
  alert(products[index].product.category);
}
```